# How to show distinct column one time and different seperately?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the key value table

```
Key  value
one  rose
one  apple
one  Grapes
```

result showing like this

```
Key value
one rose
    apple
    Grapes
```

Comment: That kind of task belongs to the client application and not to the relational enginge. I advise against even trying that.

Comment: Using your key value table (and nothing else), I don't see how you can make sure the values come out as rose, apple, Grapes.  There is nothing to force that order

Answer (score 1):

This really is something that the display layer should handle.  But it can be done in SQL Server.  The below sample should show you the basic method.

**The Setup**

```
DECLARE @SampleTable AS TABLE
    (
    Keys VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Val VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @SampleTable
    (Keys, Val)
VALUES ('one', 'rose')
    , ('one', 'apple')
    , ('one', 'grapes')
    , ('two', 'boxes')
    , ('two', 'jars')
    , ('three', 'ships');

SELECT Keys, Val
FROM @SampleTable;
```

**The Query, using ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY with a CASE statement to selectively hide the key name.**

```
WITH CTE_Table AS
    (
    SELECT S.Keys
        , S.Val
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.Keys ORDER BY S.Keys, S.Val) AS GroupOrder
    FROM @SampleTable AS S
    )
SELECT Keys = CASE WHEN C.GroupOrder = 1 THEN C.Keys ELSE '' END 
    , C.Val
FROM CTE_Table AS C;
```